# MongoDB: cursor.toArray возвращает Promise { <pending> }

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cursor

### Ситуация

Я написал запрос:

```
var results = db.collection('diseases').find({
  'ttl.txt': {
    $regex: data,
    $options: 'i'
  }
}).toArray();
```

### Проблема

Потом я вывожу его в консоль.

```
if (results.length > 0) {
  console.log(results);
}
```

Метод toArray должен возвращать массив найденных документов. Но он возвращает: `Promise { <pending> }`.

### Вопрос

Как мне вернуть массив найденных документов вместо этой строки?

### PS

toArray: [Ссылка на документацию](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/)

Comment: Сегодня с такой же проблемкой столкнулся) Но ниже уже есть решение)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `toArray()` Должен возвращать промис. Все верно. Вопрос думаю у вас как с промиса достать документы. Не буду перечислять все способы, напишу лишь самый простой и понятный. Вообще таких вопросов на stackoverflow куча с асинхронным кодом.

Самый простой способ написать `await` перед вызовом функции, но внешняя функция должна быть помечена `async`. Вот пример кода.

```
(async () => {
    var results = await db.collection('diseases').find({
        'ttl.txt': {
        $regex: data,
        $options: 'i'
    }}).toArray();

    if (results.length > 0) {
       console.log(results);
    }
})()
```

Если вы используете старый джс то пишите в коментариях, дополню ответ другими вариантами, а пока пару ссылок.

[Промисы](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise)

[Async/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: + из за того, что сегодня тоже столкнулся с этим) Но пришлось ставить >7.10.1 ноду, в 6.11.1 у мене чтото не работало, может я кривой)

Comment: @Tvolex не работал async/await? Здесь можно смотреть поддержку фич http://node.green/.

Comment: нашел, 6.11.1 => 33% и все Error)